# How to pass run time argument to Itemreader while running Job

Tags: spring-batch

I am using rabbit-messaging Queue and Spring batch as combination. Producer service will publish the message to queue. Here my code is consumer for which i am using spring batch to read, process and write. Here when message pushed to queue i have to trigger the job(means no controller end point) . For that purpose i am using **@RabbitListener("queue_Name)** which will listen when a new message publishes and it also receive message. Below is the code.

```
@EnableRabbit
public class Eventscheduler {

    @Autowired
    Job csvJob;

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    //@Scheduled(cron="0 */5 * ? * *")
    @RabbitListener(queues ="BulkSolve_GeneralrequestQueue")
    public void trigger(){
        Reader.batchstatus=false;
        Map<String,JobParameter> maps= new HashMap<String,JobParameter>();

        maps.put("time", new JobParameter(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters(maps);
        JobExecution execution=null;
        try {
            //JobLauncher jobLauncher = new JobLauncher();
             execution=jobLauncher.run(csvJob, jobParameters);
        } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JobRestartException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JobParametersInvalidException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("JOB Executed:" + execution.getStatus());

    }

}
```

Here my problem is here i am already reading published message then how i can pass that message pojo to ItemReader? before triggering job.SO that my ItemReader will read that message. Can any one help me to guide how to achieve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/annotation/RabbitListener.html) of `RabbitListener` annotation, your annotated method can have the message as parameter. For example:

```
@RabbitListener(queues ="BulkSolve_GeneralrequestQueue")
public void trigger(Message message){
    // use message as needed
}
```

You can then access the received message and use it as input to your job.

Comment: Hi mahmoud thanks for your quick response. Yes you are correct i also have  @Payload within method so that get the Message bind to my pojo. Here i have no clue how i can pass that message available for Itemreader before running Job?

Comment: In my case if i push 100 messages to queue. The RabbitListener will identify those messages (It will be trigger point to launch Job) here i can read and bind100 messages to pojo. Now i want to pass the List of pojo classes to Item reader to further process those List. Can you please help me how to achieve this?

Comment: I mean how to pass those List of pojo objects which i read from queue to ItemReader before running it?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that declaratively with annotations. You would need to do it programmatically with a `rabbitTemplate`, to read 100 messages and then use them as input to your job. Have you considered using the [AmqpItemReader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/amqp/AmqpItemReader.html)? You can create a job with this reader and a chunk size of 100. This approach does not require a listener on the queue.

Comment: I dont have clue how to use AmqpReader to read particular queue and how to create Job with this reader? can you Please give some sample piece of sample code.

Comment: I saw AmqpItemReader constructor need RabbitTemplate internally. Internally it use RabbitTemplate.

Comment: You can find an example in the `spring-batch-samples` module here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/AMQPJobFunctionalTests.java